# C99: Restricted Pointers to Document Thread Safety?

Tags: c, concurrency, c99, mutability, restrict-qualifier

This question isn't about the technical usage of restricted, more about the *subjective* usage. Although I might be mistaken as to how restricted technically works, in which case you should feel free to grill me for basing a question on a false premise.

Here are two examples of how I'm using restricted so far:

If I have a function that takes a pointer to a sequence of immutable chars, I don't say it's restricted, since other people are allowed to access the data via their own pointers at the same time as the function's executing, e.g. from another parallel thread. The data isn't being modified, so no problem.

However, if the function takes a pointer to a sequence of mutable chars that it might modify, I say it's restricted because the data absolutely should not be accessed in anyway from any pointer (bar the argument the function uses, obviously) during the execution of the function due to potentially inconsistent data. It also states the possibility of the data being modified, so the coder knows not to read stale data and that they should use a memory barrier when accessing or whatever...

I don't code much C, so I could easily be wrong about what I'm assuming here. Is this correct usage of restrict? Is it worth doing in this scenario?

I'm also assuming that once the restricted pointer is popped off the stack when the function returns, that the data can then freely be accessed via any other pointer again, and that the restriction only lasts as long as the restricted pointer. I know that this relies on the coder following the rules, since accessing a restricted data via an 'unofficial' pointer is UB.

Have I got all of this right?

EDIT:

I'd just like to make clear that I already know it does absolutely *nothing* to prevent the users from accessing data via multiple threads, and I also know that C89 has no knowledge of what 'threads' even are.

But given that any context where an argument can be modified via reference, it's clear that it mustn't be accessed as the function is running. This doesn't do anything to *enforce* thread safety, but it does clearly document that you modify the data through your own pointer during the execution of the function *at your own risk*.

Even if threading is taken completely out of the equation, you still allow for further optimizations in a scenario where it seems correct to me.

Even so, thanks for all your authoritative answers so far. Do I upvote all the answers that I liked, or just the one that I accept? What if more than one is accepted? Sorry, I'm new here, I'll look through the FAQ more thoroughly now...

Comment: About `restricted` vs optimization: here's a [paper](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~mock/papers/clei2004.pdf) saying that `restricted` is too complicated for humans to handle (vs. code generators or compilers), and that optimization is negligible - so it is too dangerous to try. However, that was on 2004, and GCC 4.5 rewrote its support for `restricted` in 2010, so things might have changed since then…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`restrict` has nothing to do with thread safety.  In fact, the existing C standards have nothing to say on the topic of threads at all; from the point of view of the spec, there is no such thing as a "thread".

`restrict` is a way to inform the compiler about *aliasing*.  Pointers often make it hard for the compiler to generate efficient code, because the compiler cannot know at compile time whether two pointers actually refer to the same memory.  Toy example:

```
void foo(int *x, int *y) {
    *x = 5;
    *y = 7;
    printf("%d\n", *x);
}
```

When the compiler processes this function, it has no idea whether `x` and `y` refer to the same memory location.  Therefore it does not know whether it will print `5` or `7`, and it  has to emit code to actually read `*x` before calling `printf`.

But if you declare `x` as `int *restrict x`, the compiler *can* prove that this function prints `5`, so it can feed a compile-time constant to the `printf` call.

Many such optimizations become possible with `restrict`, especially when you are talking about operations on arrays.

But none of this has anything to do with threads.  To get multi-treading applications right, you need proper synchronization primitives like mutexes, condition variables, and memory barriers...  All of which are specific to your platform, and none of which have anything to do with `restrict`.

[edit]

To answer your question about using `restrict` as a form of documentation, I would say "no" to that, also.

You seem to be thinking that you should document *when* a variable can or cannot be concurrently accessed.  But for shared data, the proper discipline is (almost always) to ensure that it is *never* concurrently accessed.

The relevant documentation for a variable is *whether* it is shared at all and *which mutex* protects it.  Any code accessing that variable for any reason, even just to read it, needs to hold the mutex.  The author should neither know nor care whether some other thread might or might not happen to be accessing the variable concurrently...  Because that other thread will be obeying the same discipline, and the mutex guarantees there is no concurrent access.

This discipline is simple, it works, and it scales, which is why it is one of the dominant paradigms for sharing data between threads.  (The other is message passing.)  If you ever find yourself trying to reason "do I really need to lock the mutex this time?", you are almost certainly doing something wrong.  It would be hard to overstate this point.

Comment: 6 seconds ahead, you must be typing much faster than me :)

Comment: I believe `restrict int *x` is invalid, unless the standard allows this as an alternate way of writing it. I think you mean `int *restrict x;`

Comment: I think this plus the edit covers the most as an answer, hence it's accepted.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think that this is a good dialect to provide any information about acces from different threads. It is meant as assertions about pointers that a particular peace of code gets for different pointers it handles. Threading is not part of the language, yet. Thread safe acces to data needs much more, `restrict` is not the right tool. `volatile` isn't a guarantee, which you sometimes see proposed as well.

- mutexes or other lock structures
- memory fences that ensure data integrity
- atomic operations and types

The upcoming standard C1x is supposed to provide such constructs. C99 isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example of `restrict` is `memcpy()` - which the manpage on OS X 10.6 gives the prototype as:

```
void* memcpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2, size_t n);
```

The source and destination regions in `memcpy` are not permitted to overlap; therefore by labelling them as `restrict` this restriction is enforced - the compiler can know that no part of the source array aliases with the destination; can it can do things like read a large chunk of the source and then write it into the destination.

Essentially `restrict` is about assisting compiler obtimizations by tagging pointers as not aliasing - in and of itself it doeen't help with thread safety - it doesn't automatically cause the object pointed to be to locked while the function is called.

See [How to use the restrict qualified in C](http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/cc_restrict.html) and the [wikipedia article on restrict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) for a more lengthy discussion.

Comment: So would you say that it should be used for documenting non-thread-safe data being passed to functions?

Comment: I'm more thinking along the lines of a hint for coders using the functions, as well as being an optimization for a scenario where I know it _shouldn't_ be accessed via more than one pointer rather than it _can't_ be accessed. It's only meant to _document_ the thread-safety thing; I know that it doesn't _enforce_ good practice, but are there any mechanisms in C that do? :p

Comment: @Louis (1): Not really. Restrict exists because by default in C two pointer arguments are allowed to point to the same underlying data (alias). Adding `restrict` to a pointer removes this assumption - the object pointed to can only be accessed by that pointer; and no other.

Comment: @Louis (2): In which case there isn't any C construct which can tag that something is thread-safe (it sounds like you're after something similar to `synchronized` in Java). In your situation I'd handle this either by the naming of the variable or by suitable comments.

Comment: OK, I've got what you're saying so far. But given that references to mutable data parameters _can_ be restricted in most of the code I write, surely doing so would be an optimization even in scenarios where threading is completely absent. Surely the optimization for the compiler is good enough reason to do it regardless? Just wondering...

Comment: @Louis: Yes, if you have two (or more) pointers and you know that what they point to does not alias; then marking them as `restrict` can potentially help the compiler optimise your code.

Answer (score 1):

`restrict` is a hint to the compiler that the buffer accessed via a pointer is not aliased via another pointer in scope. So if you have a function like:

```
foo(char *restrict datai, char *restrict dataj)
{
    // we've "promised" the compiler that it should not worry about overlap between 
    // datai and dataj buffers, this gives the compiler the opportunity to generate 
    // "better" code, potentially mitigating load-store issues, amongst other things
}
```

To not use `restrict` is not enough to provide guarded access in a multi-threaded application though. If you have a shared buffer simultaneously accessed by multiple threads via `char *` parameters in a read/write way you would potentially need to use some kind of lock/mutex etc - the absence of `restrict` does not imply thread safety.

Hope this helps.